# How do I find a wifi printer with KDE?

Tags: printing, kde

I was able to connect to my printer easily using Mate desktop printer setup. I cannot find the printer on KDE printer setup. Is there an easy way to find a wifi printer on KDE?

Comment: You have provided no release details, and most things done in Ubuntu-MATE can be achieved in a similar way with Kubuntu. Some more details, including release details will help us to see your issue.

Comment: Thank you guiverc. I used a live USB downloaded yesterday: "kubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64.iso." Today I noticed that Kubuntu was connected to a wifi extender rather than the source wifi router. I connected to the source router and the printer was found.

Comment: Please write your own answer, and in time you'll be able to accept it (thus gaining *rep* points). Also well done !

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I noticed that I was connected to a wifi extender rather than the source wifi router. I connected to the same router as the printer and the printer was found.